# Use of undeclared identifier in c++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to create a scroll method to move my background sprites. But when I refer to the background sprite in the method i get this message:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'bg2'
```

This is how I'm trying to use bg2 in scroll method:

```
   void scroll() {

    Point pos2 = bg2.getPosition();

    pos1.x -= 5.0f;
    pos2.x -= 5.0f;

    if(pos1.x <=-(visibleSize.width*0.5f) )
    {
        pos1.x = pos2.x + winSize.width;
    }

    if(pos2.x <=-(winSize.width*0.5f) )
    {
        pos2.x = pos1.x + winSize.width;
    }

    background1.setPosition(pos1);
    background2.setPosition(pos2);


}
```

But I declared bg2 in helloWorld.h, like this:

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
// there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

// Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
virtual bool init();  

// a selector callback
void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);

// implement the "static create()" method manually
CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);

//windows size
cocos2d::Size visibleSize;
cocos2d::Point origin;

//state machines
char gameState;
char playerState;

//sprites
cocos2d::Sprite* player;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg1;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg2;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg3;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg4;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg5;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg6;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg7;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg8;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg9;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg10;
cocos2d::Sprite* bg11;

bool onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event * event);
void onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event * event);
void onTouchEnded(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event * event);
void scroll();
```

};

I also defined bg2 in the init method of helloWorld.cpp

```
 //define background
bg1 = Sprite::create("005_chao_base.png");
bg1->setAnchorPoint(Point(0,0));
bg1->setPosition(Point(0, 0));
this->addChild(bg1,-1);

bg2 = Sprite::create("005_chao_base.png");
bg2->setAnchorPoint(Point(0,0));
bg1->setPosition(Point(bg1->getBoundingBox().size.width, 0));
this->addChild(bg2,-1);
```

I'm declaring the scroll method like this in .cpp

```
void scroll() {

}
```

and in .h

```
void scroll();
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now it's very hard to say what the problem might be.

Comment: you say you defined bg2 in the init method of helloWorld.cpp, but you posted a definition of bg1

Comment: Use `bg2->getPosition()` (i.e., arrow operator `->` to call member of pointer to object).

Comment: Secondly "I also defined bg2 in the init method of helloWorld.cpp" I see `bg1` not `bg2`.

Comment: changed it. take a look

Comment: I took a look, take a look at my answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cocos2d::Sprite` is a pointer notice the `*`. So it would be `bg2->getPosition()`

also, you are doing `cocos2d::Sprite* bg2;`
but using: `bg1 = Sprite::create("005_chao_base.png");`

also, get in the habit of name spacing everything. You are inconsistent. Sometimes you use `cocos2d::Sprite*` others you dont use `cocos2d::`

Edit: Also, you should namespace scroll like `HelloWorld::Scroll` in .cpp

Answer (score 1):

- `void scroll()` is a member function of your class.
- You are declaring in the `.cpp` another `void scroll()` and you want inside it to refer to member variable `bg2` of `class HelloWorld`, in which case you are getting the error "undeclared identifier". The reason for this is that non member function `void scroll()` has no knowledge of the `HelloWorld` class definition. So you problem is that **you are missing the class identifier from your `scroll` function.**
- The solution is to put in front of the `void scroll()` function defined in your `.cpp` the class identifier (e.g., `HelloWorld::scroll()`), see code below:

---

```
void HelloWorld::scroll()
{
  Point pos2 = bg2->getPosition();
  ...
}
```

- Remove from your `.h` the forward declaration `void scroll();`.
- Use arrow operator `->` to call `getPosition()` from `bg2`. `bg2` is a pointer.
- And you should be OK.

Comment: he doesn't have to remove `void scroll` from his .h

Comment: @GameDeveloper why? According to your opinion a floating declaration of a function that doesn't have definition is a good thing?

Comment: it does have definition though in the .cpp. why not declare in in the header? I guess it is a matter of opinion but I like being able to look at a header and know what's in the cpp.

Comment: @GameDeveloper obviously, you haven't understand what seems to be the OP's problem. His problem is that his is trying to define the `void scroll()` member function in the `.cpp` without the class identifier. I'm not suggesting to him/her to get rid of the `scroll` function but instead to put the class identifier in front of it (i.e., `HelloWorld::scroll()`). Thus, a declaration is not needed in the `.h` because there will not be any non member function `void scroll()` to declare anymore but rather the member function `HelloWorld::scroll()` that is declared in `HelloWorld` class's definition.

Comment: I understand his problem completely, I answered it too. I'm just saying that he doesn't have to remove it. Its technically optional. Maybe he likes to keep his headers in sync so one can read them without glancing at an API. Or maybe he plans to create Doxygen Docset in the future.

Comment: @GameDeveloper you spotted the error after my answer and altered/edited your question. At first you were referring only to the `->` issue. Which BTW I've mentioned first in the comments. Fortunately, SO keeps tracks of edits. Trying to devalue my answer with hocus pocus comments is dishonest. P.S chat is over.

Comment: I did nothing of the sort. I was in process of my answer and did it in stages as he hadn't posted everything. Please dont go there. Now you are trying to detract from the fact removing `void scroll();` is optional by saying I copied your answer. I wasn't trying to get in a pissing match just point out it is optional. That is clear. You're right conversation over. We are here trying to help others.

Answer (score 0):

If compiler says you use undefined symbol, then the symbol is not defined with wrong type; it is NOT defined.

Check if you included `helloWorld.h` in your .cpp module source.